# How to track bandwidth usage for web app accounts?

Tags: bandwidth

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Measure SAAS App Bandwidth Usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9694953/measure-saas-app-bandwidth-usage)

What would be the the best way to track monthly bandwidth usage for accounts in a rails web app where each account has it's own domain or sub-domain. Some kind of log parser?  I've seen some apps doing this but not sure how.

Comment: You might try this on serverfault...  Sounds like an easy task for Apache with vhosts.

Comment: This is something your web host should be able to provide as well.

Comment: Since this was asked a while ago, I believe you might have an answer. Would you mind sharing if there is one for RoR? Thanks!